# How to send non-collection based push to a client with Meteor?

Tags: meteor

I would like to make a file upload to the Meteor app and once the uploaded file is processed on the server, push to the client (only to the one who uploaded the file) some notification about successful upload. I think I know how to make file uploading by hooking into the Express, but how do I push (or callback) only to this one client?

Answer (score 0):

Use methods : http://docs.meteor.com/#methods_header

**Server side js**

```
Meteor.methods({
    'mytask' : function(var1,var2) { 
        //do stuff
        return {url:'a url'};
    }
});
```

**Client side js**

```
//Run this to call the method
Meteor.call("mytask", "www.google.com", "www.bing.com", function(err, result) {
    if(!err) {
        alert(result);
    }
}
```

Comment: Hm, but how can the server sends something to a particular client? Just one? Without being a response of a method call from a client?